# Algebraic solution for a system of algebraic equations?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-equations

How would one solve algebraically the following system of algebraic equations? 
$$f(a,b):=a(1-b)+ab\frac a{a+b}.$$
$$u = f(a,b),\quad v = f(b,a).$$
Solve algebraically $(a,b)$ in terms of $(u,v)$

---

Multiplying both sides of the equations by $a+b$ would give us a system of cubic equations. But that does not seem to help much in solving the equations.

Comment: You can use the Grobner bases approach, to set up a system of equations, and eliminate a and b from the system:
f[a_, b_] := a (1 - b) (a + b) + a b a;
GroebnerBasis[{u (a + b) - f[a, b], v (a + b) - f[b, a]}, {a, b}, {u, 
  v}]
This does not give any output, so I interpret this as what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: I am not familiar with Gröbner basis. Could you please describe the approach in details and formulate an answer? Also your $f(a,b)$ is my $f(a,b)$ multiplied by $a+b$, right? How do you reach your conclusion of impossibility exactly?

Comment: Right, I cleared the denominators, since Grobner bases deals with polynomials, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis for info. A standard reference is https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319167206

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Thank you very much for the references. However, could you please write out your derivation of the unsolvability in details as a formal answer below? I would like to see the Gröbner basis in action. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such type questions.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Could you please check out user64494's machine solution below? Why is it different from your conclusion? Is it because the methods are different?

Comment: @Hans: Ah, Grobner bases can only find polyonmial expressions (or rational, with some trickery), so the square roots showing up comes from a more general method.
I was too quick and interpreted 'algebraic' as 'polynomials', which of course is not correct.
I am sure that the mehods used for user64494's computation uses Grobner basis also, as an intermediate step.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: I see. What would be that more general method that uses the Gröbner basis as an intermediate step? Could you please provide some references on that just as you did for the Gröbner basis?

Comment: @Hans So, the Grobner basis spits out a sequence  of polynomials in say 1,2,3... variables. The zeros of the univariate polynomial can then be substituted into the bivariate polynomial, etc.. This is described on the wikipedia page I linked.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Are you talking about this section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implicitization_of_a_rational_curve? This is the way to deal with rational as opposed to polynomial equations?

Comment: @user64494: I actually posted the question on mathematics.stackexchange.com first but did not get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mechanized in current CASes, e.g. the command of Maple 2019.1

```
solve({a*(1 - b) + a*b*a/(a + b) = u, eval(a*(1 - b) + a*b*a/(a + b), {a = b, b = a}) = v}, {a, b}, explicit);
```

performs a long output which can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wd89oddvbjt99bk/solution.pdf?dl=0) exported as a PDF file.

Addition. The command of Mathematica

```
Reduce[{a*(1 - b) + a*b*a/(a + b) == u, b*(1 - a) + b^2*a/(a + b) == v}, {a, b}]//ToRadicals
```

produces

> (u == 1 - v && 
>      a == 1 && (b == 1/2 (v - Sqrt[v] Sqrt[4 + v]) || 
>        b == 1/2 (v + Sqrt[v] Sqrt[4 + v]))) || ((a == (2 + u)/4 - 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u - v + 
>              1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))) - 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/2 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u + 1/3 (-2 u - v) - 
>              v - (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(
>              1/3)) - (-(-2 - u)^3 + 4 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) - 
>                 8 (u + v - u v - v^2))/(4 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u -
>                     v + 1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                       1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 
>                       5 v^2 - 3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>                    3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                      27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                      27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))))) || 
>        a == (2 + u)/4 - 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u - v + 
>              1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))) + 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/2 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u + 1/3 (-2 u - v) - 
>              v - (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(
>              1/3)) - (-(-2 - u)^3 + 4 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) - 
>                 8 (u + v - u v - v^2))/(4 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u -
>                     v + 1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                       1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 
>                       5 v^2 - 3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>                    3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                      27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                      27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))))) || 
>        a == (2 + u)/4 + 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u - v + 
>              1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))) - 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/2 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u + 1/3 (-2 u - v) - 
>              v - (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(
>              1/3)) + (-(-2 - u)^3 + 4 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) - 
>                 8 (u + v - u v - v^2))/(4 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u -
>                     v + 1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                       1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 
>                       5 v^2 - 3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>                    3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                      27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                      27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))))) || 
>        a == (2 + u)/4 + 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u - v + 
>              1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3))) + 
>          1/2 [Sqrt](1/2 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u + 1/3 (-2 u - v) - 
>              v - (2^(
>                 1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 
>                   3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                   27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                   9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                   27 (u + v - u v - 
>                      v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(
>              3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                27 (u + v - u v - 
>                   v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                      3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                     27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                     9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                     27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(
>              1/3)) + (-(-2 - u)^3 + 4 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) - 
>                 8 (u + v - u v - v^2))/(4 [Sqrt](1/4 (-2 - u)^2 - 2 u -
>                     v + 1/3 (2 u + v) + (2^(
>                       1/3) (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 3 u^2 v - 
>                       5 v^2 - 3 u v^2))/(3 (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
>                    3 2^(1/3)))((2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                      27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                      9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                      27 (u + v - u v - 
>                       v^2)^2 + [Sqrt](-4 (6 u - 5 u^2 + 6 v - 11 u v - 
>                       3 u^2 v - 5 v^2 - 3 u v^2)^3 + (2 (2 u + v)^3 + 
>                       27 (-2 - u)^2 (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       72 (2 u + v) (-u^2 - u v) - 
>                       9 (-2 - u) (2 u + v) (u + v - u v - v^2) + 
>                       27 (u + v - u v - v^2)^2)^2))^(1/3)))))) && -1 + 
>        a != 0 && b == (a - u - v)/(-1 + a) && a^2 - u - v != 0)

Comment: Thank you. So there exists an algebraic (radical) solution contrary to what Per Alexandersson claims? Does the difference in claim coming from perhaps Maple and Mathematica use different methods than the Gröbner basis or the two are more powerful than the software Per Alexandersson is using?